# Sending hidden data via button press using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

I'm creating a Twitter/Reddit style website. I've been wondering what is the best way to securely send the in-depth details of comment data via a reply button press, grabbing it in JS and sending it back to my database

If there are 100 comments with 100 reply buttons, can I store the comment ID in the value field of the button or is this too open? My feelings are that even if users know the ID values of the comment they reply to, anyone that attempts to abuse a system with spam would get automatically limited or banned via server side detection.

Note that on the server side, a user already has a session so spam should be quite visible... right?

I've seen the option to use type="hidden", eg:

but it seems this can be pulled with a little jquery anyway. Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple but very important rule of thumb: _"Never ever rely on client side / user provided data!"_. All data on the client side can be manipulated one way or the other. No matter how hard you try to hide, obscure, obfuscate or even encrypt the data, if it's client side, someone can mess with it. Client side "security" should be used to make the life of the visitors easier. Like errors for wrong input. All or your real security must be done server side!

Comment: As for spam prevention, there are several ways to do this, but this completely depends on how you're making your forum. Easiest way is to just add a session variable called `lastPostTime` or whatever is clear enough for you on your server. Update that to the current time upon the user making a post. Then it's a simple matter of checking the time between the last post and a new one to determine whether the user is spamming or not. If time difference is lower than say 5 or 10 secs, you can just block the post.

Comment: You want to know if whether or not it's okay to store a comment ID on an attribute of a button? If so, it really depends on you. But the user *probably* can see the comments IDs regardless of what you do and how hard you try. Of course your efforts can make it harder for the user to see the comment ids or other stuff. Anyway, you are better off handling the spams on the server and stop worrying *too* much about the things that **should** be handled by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. According to me you can do one thing convert the each comment id into an unique hash then add that value in the button field and while submitting the reply convert that unique hash into the id in the server side only and if id not matched then consider it as a spam and send internal server error message.